# Editing a template with links

Tags: website, templates

I downloaded a free template, and am trying to edit it with a WYSIWYG editor (Kompozer).  So, I opened the index.html file in the template folder and wrote a few words in the first page (or link?).  However, when I click on other links on the left, what I wrote in the first page stays.  Shouldn't I get a blank page on the other links in which I can write in new information?

A template example would be:

http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/simple/087/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the links.   If they are linking to an anchor within one page (they'd have a href like "page1.html#link1" or even simply "#" if it's merely a placeholder) then the link actually points to a specific spot within that one page.  You may need to modify the links to point to a different document.

Comment: It looks like this in the code, and the links are simply "#': [code]</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>[/code]